# Is it possible to generate the below dictionary with one line of code in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

The below code:

```
import datetime as dt

fruit_lst = ['apple','orange','pear']
fruit_dict = {}
fruit_dict['datetime'] = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
for fruit in fruit_lst:
    fruit_dict[fruit] = 0
```

Produces this dictionary:

```
{'datetime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 'apple': 0,
 'orange': 0,
 'pear': 0}
```

Is it possible (or desirable) to re-write that code into one line and generate the same output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
fruit_dict = dict(datetime=dt.datetime(2020,1,1), **{f:0 for f in fruit_lst})

print(fruit_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{'datetime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'apple': 0, 'orange': 0, 'pear': 0}
```

but your explicit for-loop is more readable. I'd keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment on the importance of the readability.